# Schema.org type for a study course

Tags: schema.org

I haven't been able to find any Schema.org type that fits a sheet describing the properties of a course from a university.

The HTML (without any semantic markup using Schema.org) would look more or less like this:

```html
<section>
    <h2>Fact sheet</h2>
    <p><strong>Formal qualifications:</strong> Bachelor’s Degree in Design</p>
    <p><strong>Credits</strong>: 240 ECTS</p>
    <p><strong>Duration</strong>: 4 academic years or 240 ECTS</p>
    <p><strong>School period</strong>: from October to June</p>
    <p><strong>Timetable</strong>: Morning Group: from Monday to Friday from 9am to 2.30pm. Evening Group: from Monday to Friday from 3:30 pm to 9.00 pm * The college reserves the right to modify schedules.</p>
    <strong>Price</strong>: 112 €/ 1 ECTS
    …
</section>
```

I thought about using `Product`, but it lacks lots of things.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you look for a Google Rich Snippet, or do you look for a Schema.org type?

Comment: As I understand (https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2722261?hl=en) Google Rich Snippets is just a designation that includes Microdata, Microformats and RDFa, not a type of snippet itself.

Anyway, I was referring to Schema.org :)

Comment: Schema.org is a vocabulary which consists of *many* types/classes; Google currently recognizes only a small subset of this vocabulary for enhancing their search results: these enhancements are called (Google) Rich Snippets. Other search engines may support other Schema.org types and name their use differently.

Comment: Any luck with this? Interestingly, I noticed this in the wild as of yesterday: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/233981/seeklearning-diploma-of-financial-planning.png - At first, it looks like a "Google Rich Snippet" but it isn't as far as I can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this thread still appears on search engines, perhaps it's better to update that a Course schema was released lately: 
http://schema.org/Course

Google is also endorsing it at this moment: 
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/courses (So far I haven't seen rich snippets "live" though).

I have implemented this and I have to admit that it is not exhaustive and there is still work to be done to improve it. I noticed that Coursera.org is using properties that are not released yet, so I believe that more properties will be coming soon.

For your information!

Answer (score 2):

I would look into the Event part of the schema.org:

> An event happening at a certain time and location, such as a concert,
>   lecture, or festival.    Ticketing information may be added via the
>   'offers' property. Repeated events may be structured as separate Event
>   objects.

http://schema.org/Event

That seems like it should cover something like a course. (lecture)